# Navigation drop-down keeps pushing element down below

Tags: html, css

Having a problem with my navigation bar. When it drops down it seems to keep pushing my classes named .banner-left and .banner-right.

ill put my code on JSfiddle as i'm doing this for a project and have to use Harvard referencing so sources back to here increase the plagiarism percentage even if the work isn't leached elsewhere.

```
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/wuqa5y87
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your dropdown's `position` to `absolute`.

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wuqa5y87/1/)

```
nav ul ul {
    display:none; 
    position: absolute; }
```

Comment: Breaks the nav and changes to inline instead of dropdown, same applies to cory's response

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding position:absolute to nav ul li:hover > ul

```
nav ul li:hover > ul  { 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to an updated fiddle: looks like your original (missing rounded edges on last - but you can figure out how to get those back I am sure)

http://jsfiddle.net/wuqa5y87/2/

```
nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul ul li{
    position: relative;
    clear: both;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It removed the hover color but i re-applied it from another element, thanks :]

Comment: Nice - happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

As the other folks said, you need absolute positioning on the UL element that is shown because that takes it out of the normal flow of the document.

I've updated your fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/ryanore/wuqa5y87/3/

You'll also need a little extra massaging to get it right

```
nav ul { 
    text-align:center; 
    margin:auto; 
    position: absolute;
```

}

```
nav ul li ul{
  width: 175px;
```

}

Comment: Thanks you, need all the help i can get. :]